# Confirmation when closing window with 'X' button with MVVM light

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I am using WPF and MVVM Light framework (I am new in using them).

I want to do the following:

1. When the user click on the 'X' close button, I want to display a confirmation window if whether he wants to exit the application or not.
2. If yes, the application closes
3. If no, nothing happens and he can still use the application as per normal

So far, I have this:

- In MainWindow.xaml.cs:

  ```
  public MainWindow()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
      Closing += (s, e) => ViewModelLocator.Cleanup();
  }
  ```
- In ViewModelLocator.cs:

  ```
  public static void Cleanup()
  {
      ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>().Cleanup();
  }
  ```
- In MainViewModel.cs:

  ```
  public override void Cleanup()
  {
      MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(
                      "Unsaved data will be lost, would you like to exit?",
                      "Confirmation",
                      MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
                      MessageBoxImage.Question);

      if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
      {
        // clean-up resources and exit
      }
      else
      {
        // ????
      }
  ```

Actually, if the user answers 'Yes' or 'No', in both cases the application will exit.

I am not too sure how to proceed from here...

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an `EventToCommand` in an `EventTrigger` to catch the closing event and set the `Cancel` property of the passed `CancelEventArgs` to true if you want to cancel the closing:

**XAML:**

```
<Window ...
   xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
   xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF45"
   DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
         <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding OnClosingCommand}" 
            PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
      </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <Grid>
     ...
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
   public RelayCommand<CancelEventArgs> OnClosingCommand { get; set; }

   public MainViewModel()
   {
      this.OnClosingCommand = 
         new RelayCommand<CancelEventArgs>(this.OnClosingCommandExecuted);
   }

   private void OnClosingCommandExecuted(CancelEventArgs cancelEventArgs)
   {
      ...

      if (mustCancelClosing)
      {
         cancelEventArgs.Cancel = true;
      } 
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jürgen! I tried your solution and it works like a charm :-)

Comment: You are welcome :-) You know that you can accept an answer by clicking the check mark on the left hand side of the answer?

Answer (score 2):

The `Closing` event arguments have a `Cancel` property that you need to set to `true` if the user cancels the close. Therefore, your `Cleanup()` method should return `bool` and you should assign it to the `Cancel` property.